# phantomjs // render webpage from give dom

Tags: node.js, screen-scraping, phantomjs, screen-capture

is there any chance to render/process a webpage just from the given DOM?
At the moment we can use `page.open` but just with a url. In my app i've got the DOM from somewhere else so there is no need to get it twice :)

I now that you can set the page content via `page.content = "<html></html>"` but i'm missing the callback for loaded images, etc.

Any Ideas out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/)' [`bbcshot.js`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/samples/bbcshots.js) code sample, it does quite exactly what you're asking for.